# polymorphism in dozer

Tags: java, polymorphism, dozer

I have four classes:

```
public class A { }
public class B extends A { }
public class C extends B { }
public class D extends B { }
```

From what I read in the dozer documentation regarding inheritance, it must be pretty straight forward, I need to map super classes to each other, and as well for sub classes.
Here is how it looks in the xml:

```
<mapping>
<class-a>foo.A</class-a>
<class-b>foo.bar.A</class-b>
</mapping>

<mapping>
<class-a>foo.B</class-a>
<class-b>foo.bar.B</class-b>
</mapping>

<mapping>
<class-a>foo.C</class-a>
<class-b>foo.bar.C</class-b>
</mapping>

<mapping>
<class-a>foo.D</class-a>
<class-b>foo.bar.D</class-b>
</mapping>
```

All these classes are identical, by that I mean D and D are having the same attributes, C and C and so on.

**Problem:**
In the object I am passing to dozer, I have an attribute of type B, which could be initialized by C or D (polymorphism). 
When dozer gives back the new mapped object, it will always return the attribute type of B to me, and not C or D.
How to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Please, take a look at the [Inheritance Mapping section](http://dozer.sourceforge.net/documentation/baseattributes.html). You can use such a mapping for a field class with subclasses.

```
<mapping>
    <class-a>foo.Source</class-a>
    <class-b>foo.Dest</class-b>
    <field>
      <a>attr</a>
      <b>attr</b>
      <a-hint>foo.B, foo.C, foo.D</a-hint>
      <b-hint>foo.bar.B, foo.bar.C, foo.bar.D</b-hint>
   </field>
</mapping>
```

EDIT: I implement some type of automatically polymorphism [feature request](https://github.com/DozerMapper/dozer/issues/57). I think, it will be included in the next Dozer release.

Answer (score 0):

**-** I think you need an `explicit cast`.

**Eg:**

```
B b = new C();

go(b)

//////////Called Method////////////////

public void go(B bx){

    C c = (C) bx;

}
```

Comment: well I know this, the problem is how to do it with dozer